# Live math on serial data stream

Tags: bash, awk, gps, hardware

I have a hardware GPS that prints out some data:

```sh
sudo cat /dev/ttyGPS_Device | grep -a GPRMC
```

It prints every half second or so and looks like this:

> $GPRMC,171450.000,A,4239.245592,N,07349.887355,W,0.000,116.6,150420,,,A*74
>   $GPRMC,171503.000,A,4239.245592,N,07349.887355,W,0.000,116.6,150420,,,A*73
>   $GPRMC,171504.000,A,4239.245592,N,07349.887355,W,0.000,116.6,150420,,,A*74

I can filter out just the Lattitude and Longitude by doing:

```sh
sudo cat /dev/ttyACM2 | stdbuf -oL grep -a GPRMC | stdbuf -oL cut -d',' -f 4-7 | tr ',' '\t'
```

And that output looks much nicer:

> 4239.245592   N   07349.887355    W
>   4239.245592   N   07349.887355    W
>   4239.245592   N   07349.887355    W

I would like to be able to do some math and formatting on the data. Specifically leading zeroes need to become '-' and both values must be multiplied by 100.
Desired output:

> 42.39245592   N   -73.49887355    W
>   42.39245592   N   -73.49887355    W
>   42.39245592   N   -73.49887355    W

I would be OK with a non `bash` solution, however I prefer a nice one liner. The hardware I am using to get GPS data is a [Ericsson H5321 gw Mobile Broadband Module](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Ericsson_H5321_gw_Mobile_Broadband_Module#GPS)

Comment: `bash` can't handle floating point arithmetic, use `awk`

Comment: Hint: `awk` can replace your `grep`, `cut` and `tr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append GNU awk:

```
| awk '{printf("%.8f %s -%.8f %s\n",$1/100,$2,$3/100,$4)}'
```

Output:

```
42.39245592 N -73.49887355 W
42.39245592 N -73.49887355 W
42.39245592 N -73.49887355 W
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner shell:

```sh
xargs -I"{}" -l1 sh -c 'IFS=,;set -- $1;LC_NUMERIC=C;printf "%f N %f W\n" "$4" "$6"' {}
```

Obviously as [@DiegoTorresMilano mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234872/live-math-on-serial-data-stream#comment108329193_61234872), shell arithmetic only handles integers, so no scaling of the values.